# Can anyone help me Identify this model?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx, chrome

[image][image]I have the serial # YC00C07024. Also will attach pics of the bike.
Wondering what the value is?
Thanks!

Comment: Waiting for the pictures

Comment: https://knowyourbike.com/dyno/air